# free dual pane file manager for Mac OS X with tabs

Tags: macos, file-management

does **free dual pane file manager for Mac OS X with tabs** even exist?

I found [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com) but it doesn't have tabs.

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/138527/dual-pane-file-manager-for-mac-os-x

Comment: @ghoppe: well, I read that question but it didn't answer what I wanted to know so I hoped I can get an answer with my new question

Comment: @ghoppe "Page not found This question was removed from Super User for reasons of moderation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it and it is [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/). There is only experimental port to OS X but it works well so far!

- [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) is good as well

Answer (score 2):

[TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) is currently free, but version 1.0 will be $15.

Comment: thank you for that. I'll give it a try. I missed the 'Add a dual-panel mode (like in good old Norton Commander)' when reading about TotalFinder the first time.

Answer (score 2):

https://superuser.com/questions/138527/dual-pane-file-manager-for-mac-os-x

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers

Comment: re the SU link: "Page not found This question was removed from Super User for reasons of moderation"

Answer (score 1):

[Newton Commander](https://github.com/neoneye/newton-commander) is open source (MIT license).

I have recently made NC open source and started preparing it for Mavericks. Originally I wanted to sell it. It's a huge project, something I cannot finish myself alone. Please consider contributing.